# JQuery Ajax gives error on sending multiple data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
name = "name1";
uname = "username";
pass = "password";
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "url",
  data: {
    name: name,
    username: uname,
    password: pass
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error");
  }


});
```

This code gives an error while running :

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

But if I change the number of parameters at data to 1, it runs fine.
I tried to specify datatype, but to no avail

Comment: Whats status after putting JSON.stringify on data ?

Comment: just set var before your vars and it works. look this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkwjuwh7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data is array and not text. Try checking it again, I ran into a same issue some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried JSON.stringify? See the following code example:

**JAVASRIPT**

```
name="name1";
uname = "username";
pass = "password";

var data = { name:name , username:uname , password: pass}; 

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "url",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      alert(data); 
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

> **w3schools**
>
> A common use of JSON is to exchange data to/from a web server.
>
> When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string.
>
> Convert a JavaScript object into a string with JSON.stringify().